# Scrape data using beautiful soup

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

While Scraping data using `beautifulSoap` 
In this html code there are two `<h2>` tag but I want to extract data from second `<h2>` tag. So how can i do this?
and so on if there are multiples of same tag and i want to extract data from any one of the tag how can I do that?

Code:

```
<h2>Video Instructions For Making Soft Idlis</h2>
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/p3uF3LK5734?rel=0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
</div>

<h2>Recipe For Making Soft Idlis</h2>
```

I had thought of extracting data using keyword instead of using tag.
for example I can use `<h2>` tag and use keyword `Recipe` to find the data of second `<h2>` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> for example I can use `<h2>` tag and use keyword `Recipe` to find the data of second `<h2>` tag

Yes, you can do exactly that. You can use the Python [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) (Regular Expression) module to match partial text inside a tag.

From the **[documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression)**:

> If you pass in a regular expression object, Beautiful Soup will filter against that regular expression using its `search()` method.

**Demo:**

```
>>> import re
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> 
>>> html = '''<h2>Video Instructions For Making Soft Idlis</h2>
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/p3uF3LK5734?rel=0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
    </div>

    <h2>Recipe For Making Soft Idlis</h2>'''
>>>
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
>>> tag = soup.find('h2', text=re.compile('Recipe'))
>>> tag
<h2>Recipe For Making Soft Idlis</h2>
>>> tag.text
'Recipe For Making Soft Idlis'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know what `h2` you want based on order, you simply need to use that as an index to the return of `.findAll` method:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup('''<h2>Video Instructions For Making Soft Idlis</h2>
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/p3uF3LK5734?rel=0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
</div>

<h2>Recipe For Making Soft Idlis</h2>''', "html.parser")
```

---

```
>>> soup.findAll("h2")[1]
<h2>Recipe For Making Soft Idlis</h2>
```

Comment: if i dont know whats the order of any tag then.? How can i extract the data

Comment: You need to know something specific about the tag you want to extract the text, however you won't be able to tell your script what exact tag you need. It could a class name, a part of the text, or, as your question seemed to say, the order.